# How do I get this Fahrenheit to Celsius Code in Python to return a value instead of the formula?

Tags: python

```
def c_to_f ():
  c_temp= float(input("Enter temperature in Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit"))
  f_temp= float(1.8 *c_temp) + 32



c_to_f()
print("The value in Fahrenheit is: " + f_temp)
```

The output***:

```
Enter temperature in Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit56
The value in Fahrenheit is: float(1.8 * c_temp) + 32
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0HTu.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post your code as a text so it's easier for us to reproduce it and [format it properly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/9997212).

Comment: if you have created a function and you want some output from function you should return value in your case it should return `f_temp`

Comment: Please read [How to Ask Good Questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i apolgize for making it unclear, i'm new here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the created function object first:

```
def c_to_f (): 
    c_temp= float(input("Enter temperature in Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit")) 
    f_temp= float(1.8 *c_temp) + 32
    return f_temp
a = c_to_f() 

# Return the object as string
print("The value in Fahrenheit is: " + str(a))

# Using printf
print(f"The value in Fahrenheit is: {a}")

Enter temperature in Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit34
The value in Fahrenheit is: 93.2
The value in Fahrenheit is: 93.2
```

Comment: You're welcome :). Please accept the answer if this helps.

Comment: A better design would be to handle the I/O outside the function. Ask for input, convert to float, call the function with that, print the result.